# Getting Error while calling external api end point using javascript

Tags: javascript

I am new to JavaScript and i am trying to send api request from JavaScript.

I am getting below error while calling external endpoint from JavaScript.

> from origin 'null' has been blocked by CORS policy: Request header field x-api-key is not allowed by Access-Control-Allow-Headers in preflight response.

```
var url = "<external_api_for_graphQl"
var api_key = "<api_key>"

var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();

xhr.open("POST", url, false);
xhr.setRequestHeader("x-api-key", api_key);


xhr.send("");
alert(xhr.status);
```

any idea how we can resolve this?
Thanks

Comment: @Ravi Makwana it looks similar but i am not sure how i can solve it in my code.

Answer (score 0):

try to set header

```
xhr.setRequestHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", "*");
xhr.setRequestHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Credentials", "true");
xhr.setRequestHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Methods", "GET,HEAD,OPTIONS,POST,PUT");
xhr.setRequestHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Headers", "Access-Control-Allow-Headers, Origin,Accept, X-Requested-With, Content-Type, Access-Control-Request-Method, Access-Control-Request-Headers");
```

Comment: Thanks @Ravi Makwana i tried it but now i am getting this error ."from origin 'null' has been blocked by CORS policy: Request header field access-control-allow-origin is not allowed by Access-Control-Allow-Headers in preflight response."

Answer (score 0):

The **Access-Control-Allow-Headers** header is sent by the server to let the client know which headers it supports for CORS requests. The value of **Access-Control-Allow-Headers** should be a comma-delineated list of header names, such as `"X-Custom-Information"` or any of the standard but non-basic header names (which are always allowed).

This error occurs when attempting to preflight a header that is not expressly allowed (that is, it's not included in the list specified by the **Access-Control-Allow-Headers** header sent by the server). To fix this, the server needs to be updated so that it allows the indicated header, or you need to avoid using that header.

one think you can try is this:

```
$.ajax({
        headers: { "Accept": "application/json", "x-api-key":"<x-api-key>"},
        type: 'POST',
        url: '<external_api_for_graphQl>',
        crossDomain: true,
        beforeSend: function(xhr){
            xhr.withCredentials = true;
      },
        success: function(data, textStatus, request){
            console.log(data);
        }
```

});